# htaccess url parameter rewrite for specific page as subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to change my specific page URL as subdomain by `.htaccess` from
`example.com/page.php` to `page.example.com`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: "url parameter rewrite" - there's no "URL parameter" here? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't have any htaccess code, i am just asking for one. Thanks

Comment: "i am just asking for one" ... Please understand that this is not how this site works. This is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to _help_ , to help you sort out the issues you cannot solve yourself. And for that we need to see what you tried, so your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

We need to make some assumptions, since you've not included this information in the question:

1. You are requesting (ie. linking to) `page.example.com` and you wish to serve `/page.php`.
2. Both the subdomain `page.example.com` and domain apex `example.com` point to the same area of the filesystem, so both hostnames serve the same content.

In which case it is a relatively straight forward internal rewrite from `page.example.com` to `page.example.com/page.php` (based on assumption #2 above).

In your `.htaccess` file, you can achieve this using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(page)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ %1.php [L]
```

The `%1` backreference simply holds the value `page` from the preceding *CondPattern*.

This only matches requests for `https://page.example.com/` and not `https://page.example.com/<something>`